# How do I get all the Amiibo Gear?

Tags: splatoon-2, amiibo

I just started playing Splatoon 2 and have tried using my Amiibo's in game to unlock the special amiibo gear. However when I use the normal inkling and squid amiibos they only give me one piece of gear, and I am unable to use the Callie and Maria amiibos at all. How exactly do I get the rest of the special amiibo gear sets?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To unlock the special amiibo sets of gear you need to increase your level in Splatoon to level 7 which unlocks you the shirt of the amiibo sets once you use the amiibo again after getting to level 7. To complete the set you need to get to level 10 and use the amiibo again to unlock the shoes.

The Callie and Maria amiibos also include a special requirement for you to beat Octo Valley before you are even able to use them. Once you complete Octo Valley both the Callie and Maria amiibo work the exact same way as the other amiibos.

Comment: Wow this sounds like an entirely convoluted process.  Just curious, what's the source on this?  If amiibo unlocks are going to be this complicated I really hope Nintendo has released this info somewhere otherwise how's a regular player supposed to know this information?

Comment: I've read reddit quite a bit on this one. I have also experienced this myself since I tried reading the amiibo every level and they only started giving me the second piece at level 7 and the third piece at 10. It's just Nintendo being Nintendo. Also the Callie and Maria one make a bit of sense since they are extremely important to the story and give you spoilerish gear.

Comment: Not true. I'm lvl 17 and I;ve only got the Head gear for the squid amiibo.

Comment: Was it the first time you scanned it because it will always give you only the head the first time no matter what level you are.