# How do I get all the Amiibo Gears in Splatoon 3?

Tags: amiibo, splatoon-3

In Splatoon 3 you can get exclusive gears from Amiibos, like the previous game.
In Splatoon 2, [these were the requirements](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/314816):

> To unlock the special Amiibo sets of gear you need to increase your level in Splatoon to level 7 which unlocks you the shirt of the amiibo sets.
> To complete the set you need to get to level 10.

As far as I know, you always get the first piece of gear without doing anything special.

Is this still correct for Splatoon 3? Do I just need to level up in order to unlock more gears?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you haven’t already [earned the gear in Splatoon 2 and imported your save](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/399341/how-do-i-get-all-the-amiibo-gears-in-splatoon-3/399399#comment561199_399399), Amiibo gifts seem to be related to how many battles you've completed since scanning the Amiibo.

I scanned several amiibos at level 18 and each one only gave me shoes. When I scanned them a second time they had dialogue telling me they would have more gifts if I came back after some battles.

[image: octoling octopus asking for more time to prepare gifts]

They gave me the rest of their gifts when I rescanned my Amiibos two days later at level 21. .

[image: marina saying I've been hard at work battling]

The amiibo then let me know they had given me all of their gifts.

[image: Pearl is out of gifts]

Comment: I had the impression it wasn't related to the level, I'm 10+ now and I haven't yet received every gear. Marina said I deserve another present, but she needed some time to find it (as in your Octoling screen), so your speculation seems right to me.

Comment: If you've already done the unlocks in Splatoon 2 and use the same amiibo, you'll be given all the gear right away. At least this was my experience.

Answer (score 0):

I have scanned the Amiibos but haven't gotten the gear but my friend did and they recommend just playing lots and lots of turf wars and checking every so often to see if they think your "ready" for their gifts.

Comment: Yes, this is confirmed by Stevoisiak's answer, too

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize there was text between the pictures.